# How to get Visual Studio CMake to work with C/++ Lanuch for minGW/Cygwin (gdb)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, gdb, clang

I have created CMake Project in VS and I selected clang toolchain for compiling and "C/++ Lanuch for minGW/Cygwin (gdb)" for debugging but when i start the debugging it doesn't stop at my breakpoint. Also i have tried to load the executable to gdb (minGW) but it seems that it doesn't have any symbols.